# Error while finding spec for 'googlesamples.assistant'

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to install Google Assistant on my Raspberry Pi when I encountered this error message after executing the following line:

```
python -m googlesamples.assistant
```

Error:

```
/home/myusername/env/bin/python: Error while finding spec for 
'googlesamples.assistant' (<class 'ValueError'>: 
googlesamples.assistant.__spec__ is None)
```

---

What have I done until getting to this error?

I created the Oauth Client ID on the Google Cloud Platform (json file I used later), installed `python3-dec` , `python3-venv` , `portaudio19-dev` , `libffi-dev` and `libssl-dev`

After this I've ran:

```
python3 -m venv env
env/bin/pip install pip setuptools --upgrade
source env/bin/activate
```

I've installed the Google Assistant SDK samples, and ran `python -m googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers --client-secrets /path/to/file.json` , navigated to the website it asked me to, and completed the authentication flow. After these I wanted to run the google assistant when I experienced the error above.

I was searching a lot, but haven't found any answer, any ideas could help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no plain `googlesamples.assistant`. There are actually several demos which are available within the namespace. You can call them directly on the command line after installing without the `python -m` prefix.

`googlesamples-assistant-hotword --device_model_id 'my-model-identifier`

`googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --device-model-id 'my-device-model' --device-id 'my-device-identifier'`

`googlesamples-assistant-audiotest --record-time 10`

`googlesamples-assistant-devicetool --help`